# How to get selected values from listbox within a dialog box

Tags: matlab, listbox, dialog

I have used the following code in a GUI to open a listbox in a dialog box when a pushbutton is pushed by the user:

```
% --- Executes on button press in selectdata.
function selectdata_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to selectdata (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
X = getappdata(0,'XValue');
Y = getappdata(0,'YValue');
A = [X,Y];
str = num2str(X);
[s,v] = listdlg('PromptString','Select Initial & Final Wavelength:','SelectionMode','multiple','ListString',str);  
selected_values = get(hObject,'value');
```

I am trying to get the the values selected in the listbox but I am having difficulty in doing so as I keep getting

```
selected_values =   
                   1
```

in the comand window, which I'm presuming just means it is true.
Does anyone have an idea on how to get the selected values from the listbox in the dialog box?

Comment: I think you need to use `s` instead. `get(hObject,'value')` would get value of the pushbutton status rather.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index of the selected value will be `s`. The value will be `str{s}` or `str(s,:)`, depending on whether you have stored `str` as a character array or a cell array of strings.

`get(hObject,'value')` here is not doing what you intend - `hObject` refers to the pushbutton you pressed, not the `listdlg`, so it's getting the `value` of the pushbutton itself.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but with no luck perhaps I'm not following you correctly. 
I tried 'selected_values = get(str(s,:),'value')' and I'm getting the error  
 Error using get  
Invalid handle  

Error in MichelleLaycockGUImainwindow>selectdata_Callback (line 90)  
selected_values = get(str(s,:),'value')

Comment: No. Use `selected_values = str{s}`, or `selected_values = str(s,:)`. `listdlg` is returning the index of the selected value directly into `s`, which you can use to index directly into the set of values `str`. There are no handles involved, and no need to get any properties of anything.

Comment: I wonder could you help me further? I would like to select two values from my listbox and it allows me to do this but it only gives me the value of the last selection rather than all that have been selected. Any suggestions on how to get the others?

Comment: Actually its ok, I've changed my approach and am using two push buttons instead. Thanks for your previous help!